# Adding preloaded MediaClips to MediaComposition.Clips throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

Exception Message:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> WinRT information: Element is already in use
>
> The parameter is incorrect.

Code:

```
composition = await MediaComposition.LoadAsync(timelineCMPOutputFile);
composition2 = await MediaComposition.LoadAsync(timelineCMPOutputFile2);

//TODO: Warn user to select the oldest first.
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < composition2.Clips.Count; i++)
    {
         composition.Clips.Add(composition2.Clips[i]); // Exception throws here.
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}

var action = composition.SaveAsync(timelineCMPOutputFile);
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to merge both [MediaComposition.Clips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing) into one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition is saved as an XML file, containing metadata about the composition such as the source media files, arrangement of clips, overlays, and effects applied to the composition like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Composition>
  <Clips>
    <MediaClip ExpectedOriginalDuration="5816533125" Path="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SDKSamples.MediaEditingSample.CS_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\temp.mp4"/>
  </Clips>
</Composition>
```

The clips information we got from the XML file are not the media source's clips, they are metadata which defined the path of original source. It seems like that only clips created from media file can be added to the composition successfully. So the solution is to rendered the second loaded composition to a media file by [MediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640551) and then create a new clip from the file. At last, add the new clip to the first loaded composition to complete the mergence. Updated code as follows.

```
 StorageFile timelineCMPOutputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("timelineCMPOutputFile");
 StorageFile timelineCMPOutputFile2 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("timelineCMPOutputFile2");
 var composition = await MediaComposition.LoadAsync(timelineCMPOutputFile);
 var composition2 = await MediaComposition.LoadAsync(timelineCMPOutputFile2);
 //TODO: Warn user to select the oldest first.
 try
 {
     await composition2.RenderToFileAsync(await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting));
     StorageFile tempfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("temp.mp4");
     MediaClip firstClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(tempfile);            
     composition.Clips.Add(firstClip); /// Exception throws here.
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
 }

 var action = composition.SaveAsync(timelineCMPOutputFile);

 // Combine two video files together into one
```

Comment: Thank you Sunteen!